# Magento process payment after checkout for custom payment method

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create a custom payment module in magento. I found a lot of tutorials for this, but only ones that just add the order. My question is: How can i set the order to paid when the user clicks on checkout.

This is the relevant code i have so far:

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>

    <global>


        <models>
            <My_Module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </My_Module>
        </models>
    </global>


    <default>
        <payment>
            <mypayment>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>My_Module/Payment</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <title>Testing</title>
            </mypayment>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

Model/payment.php

```
<?php

class My_Module_Model_Payment extends Mage_Payment_model_Method_Abstract{
    protected $_code = 'mypayment';

    protected $_isInitializeNeeded      = false;
    protected $_canUseInternal          = true;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = true;
}
```

I also find it very hard to find documentation. For example, i am looking for a list of events, and a documentation for the payment method, but i do not seem to find anything. Does Magento not offer any of these?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to utilize the Varien_Object and Sales_Quote to do any custom payment of any sorts with Magento (not sure on this), and not just the abstract payment method.

Check this (the answer has a link to an actual working example of a custom payment module). 
[Magento custom payment method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991678/magento-custom-payment-method?rq=1)